# If Array include in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

I've created an array of cities

```
$cities = explode("|", $city);
```

Now I want to search that array to see if it contains a particular city for an if statement. Something like this...

```
If($cities includes(London)){
    Do code;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (in_array('London', $cities)) {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `in_array`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Example:

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [in_array()](http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array("London", $cities)) {
    Do code;
}
```